# In a given set of numbers can there be more than half above mean, median or mode?

Tags: mean, median, mode

Suppose I have a set of numbers, for example - exam scores of 20 students.

Can there be more than half of students scoring above the mean ? similarly, can more than half the class score above the median and mode ?

Comment: Yes and no. You can't  have more than half above the median; at most in the presence of ties more than half can be equal to or above the median. (Trivial example: all students get the same mark.) Otherwise imagine 9 at 0, 6 at 50 and 5 at 100. Then the mode is 0 and 11 are above. The mean is 40 and 11 are above. Many such examples.

Comment: @NickCox You should post that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: thanks @NickCox, can you share some more insights into this ? any study material ? similarly, what will be the case with mode and mean ?

Comment: Any good introductory statistics text should discuss the possibilities. @A.G. has now provided a very good analysis.

Comment: Note that "above" can be replaced by "below" simply by negating all values.  Thus, if there is *any* statistic whatsoever where the answer is always "no," then *by definition* that statistic is a median.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is **not** possible for over half of the students to score above the **median**:

- If there is an even number of students $n$, the median is the mean of the 2 scores in the "middle" of the sorted set of scores, meaning that at most half ($\frac{n}{2}$) of the students will score above or below the median.
- If there is an odd number of students $n$, the median is the number in the "middle" of the sorted set of scores. In this case, at most less than half ($\frac{n-1}{2}$, to be precise) students may score above the median.

Notice that I said "at most" above: when multiple students score *at* the median, the number of students scoring over the median must be even *less* than the $\frac{n}{2}$ or $\frac{n-1}{2}$ figures I gave above.

But is **is** possible for more than half the students to score above the **mean**: this may happen when the distribution is negatively-skewed, like in image (a) below, and the mean is below the median.

And it **is** possible for more than half the students to score above the **mode**: this may happen when the distribution is positively-skewed, like in image (c) below, and the mode is below the median.

[image]

(For the avoidance of doubt, the perfectly symmetrical distribution in image (b) above is actually a bit of a special case, where the mean exists (unlike the Cauchy distribution) and there is a single mode. If those conditions do not hold, we cannot state that the mean, median & mode coincide, so being perfectly symmetrical is neither necessary nor sufficient to do so. One famous example of such a symmetric distribution where those conditions *do* hold is the Normal/Gaussian ("bell curve") distribution.)

Comment: Good (+1). Some readers might appreciate notes that the normal is just an example of a perfectly symmetrical distribution; and that distributions being symmetrical is neither necessary nor sufficient for mode to coincide with median and mean.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've edited it to add that info.

Comment: @NickCox - In other words, "normal" is completely abnormal.

Comment: Edwin Jaynes suggested that we call it the central distribution, but I've never seen that quoted. There is always Gaussian....